# skrollr doesnt work on ipad when using doctype html

Tags: javascript, ipad, doctype, skrollr

Below code doesnt work on ipad: the page gies completely blank. Works fine on desktop browsers. If I remove the doctype, it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

            #block {
                background-color:red; 
                width:100px; height:100px; top:300px; 
                position:absolute; 
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="skrollr-body">
            <div id="block" data-0="left:0px" data-300="left:100px">test</div>
        </div> 

        <script src="js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            skrollr.init();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Strange .. using skrollr 0.6.17. Whats wrong ?

*-pike

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

seems to fix it. hm .. is that a bug ? am i missing a lib ?